# it was in my mind to put that little test

Tags: phrase-usage

I’d like to ask about the sentence from The Retired Colourman by Conan Doyle.

> Because it was in my mind to put that little test which answered so
>   admirably. I fear you would not have gone so far.

The above sentence was uttered by Holmes when asked why he cooperated with his peer, and not the police. 
I thought what he meant was simply..

> A: “it was me who chose, hence the result”.

But is there any way you can interpret this sentence as

> B: “ I was plan to do some possibly illegal thing, so I didn’t think
>   the police would have done that kind of stuff.”

In A, “little test” means to think over who I should work with, peer guy Barker, or the police. In B, “little test” probably means what Holmes would do in terms of investigation. But I think Holmes had already done everything he needed to do when he uttered this remark, so I don’t know.
Could someone tell me about this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking with those choices you're giving.  It's all gibberish. "Put that little test" is a version of the idiom "put (something) to the test," which means, "to cause (someone or something) to be in a situation that shows how strong, good, etc. that person or thing really is."  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20(someone%20or%20something)%20to%20the%20test#targetText=Definition%20of%20put%20(someone%20or,the%20team%20to%20the%20test.

Comment: The 'test' must have been asking Amberley "What did you do with the bodies?", since that was the only thing he hadn't yet done in the investigation. Thinking over who he would collaborate with isn't a test.